# C# overloading a property of an object found in a class

Tags: c#, properties, overriding, overloading, dependency-properties

I would like to know if there is a way to override a property from a class without overloading the latter.

Exemple, with new C# version, I would like to know if it's possible to override by any means the property *Street* from the **Address** class. I would like to add some data annotations of the *Street* property in the called class **Person**.

```cs
  public class Address
  {
        [Display(Name = "Street")]
        public string Street { get; set; }
  
        public string City { get; set; }
  }
```

```cs
    public class Person
    {
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }

        public Address Address { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Street with street number")]
        public new Address.Street  { get;set; } // new or override or anything to access at the Street property in the called class
    }
```

```cs
    class Program
    {
        public Person Person { get; set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var person = new Person() { Firstname = "John", Lastname = "Doe" };
            person.Address = new Address() {Street = "2 mainstreet" , City = "Chicago"};

            Console.WriteLine($"{person.Firstname} {person.Lastname} - {person.Address.Street}, {person.Address.City}");
        } 
    }
```

Comment: This is not overriding and has nothing to do with inheritance or polymorphism.

Comment: I don't know the context, but I'd argue that if you have this need, it is probably not a good idea to do this with the tool of attributes. Also, for the usage example, those attributes aren't even used.

Comment: ^^ But without that judgement: What you _could_ do is using the Adress property as private property and redirecting public properties to it in the person class. Not something I'd do, but at least it would work.

Comment: In my specific case, I would like to override the attributes of a property called in another class without break the logic and called code in the rest of the application.

Comment: You cannot override something that you don't inherit from. The `Person` class "has-a" `Address` , it's not "is-a" `Address`. So all you can do is redirect, not override.

Comment: Ok ok. It was just to find out. Since I haven't followed in detail the new features of C# 9 and 10. I was wondering if they had not allowed access to this kind of functionality.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Unrelated to the question: Are you _sure_ a Person will only ever be related to _one_ Address? ;)

Comment: No, I know. But the code is old and the business logic wants there is only one address at this stage of the view. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about inheritance usage in your case, but you can acheive this
by changing getter/setter:

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }

        public Address Address { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Street with street number")]
        public string Street  { get{return this.Address.Street; }
                               set{this.Address.Street = value;} }
    }
```

Comment: Just a little Nitpick here: This way, you can access the property via `Person.Street` _and_ `Person.Address.Street` which I wouldn't recommend doing.